# How to update docker in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ansible, docker-swarm

I installed docker engine on *Amazon Linux AMI* with command `yum install docker`. Docker version is *1.10*, and `yum update docker` states it's the latest version. Thus I can't run swarm in ec2's, as Docker version *1.12* is required. How do I update to the latest version (please note the solution should be easily applied to ansible provisioning).

Comment: did you add docker repo to your yum repos on that instance?

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE:

For the **latest Docker engine**, just type:

> ```
> curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
> ```

After updating docker, be sure you are on the right version:

```
docker -v
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e
```

Now you need to swarm update. 
Updates a swarm with new parameter values. This command must target a manager node.

```
$ docker swarm update --cert-expiry 720h
```

swarm update

```
Usage:  docker swarm update [OPTIONS]

Update the swarm

Options:
      --cert-expiry duration            Validity period for node certificates (default 2160h0m0s)
      --dispatcher-heartbeat duration   Dispatcher heartbeat period (default 5s)
      --external-ca value               Specifications of one or more certificate signing endpoints
      --help                            Print usage
      --task-history-limit int          Task history retention limit (default 5)
```

**Warning: this command is part of the Swarm management feature introduced in Docker 1.12, and might be subject to non backward-compatible changes.**

### Resource Link:

1. [swarm update](http://docs.docker.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/engine/reference/commandline/swarm_update/)
2. [How to Configure Docker Swarm](https://www.upcloud.com/support/how-to-configure-docker-swarm/)
3. [Easy Docker Orchestration With Docker 1.12, AWS EFS And The Swarm
   Mode](https://medium.com/@eon01/easy-docker-orchestration-with-docker-1-12-aws-efs-and-the-swarm-mode-87d51b6d5ad2#.3urfamb7f)
4. [Running Docker on Amazon EC2](https://seiler.it/running-docker-amazon-ec2/)
5. [Provision a Swarm cluster with Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/provision-with-machine/)

For checking purpose, I have run the command and got the latest version. I have got a difference between commands. You have used -sSL. Please use -fsSL instead of -sSL

```
skywalker@skywalker-PC:~$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
You're using 'elementary' version 'loki'.
Upstream release is 'ubuntu' version 'xenial'.
[sudo] password for skywalker: 
..............
............
Get:1 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 aufs-tools amd64 1:3.2+20130722-1.1ubuntu1 [92.9 kB]
Get:2 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 docker-engine amd64 1.12.3-0~xenial [19.3 MB]
Get:3 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 cgroupfs-mount all 1.2 [4,970 B]
Fetched 19.4 MB in 1min 23s (233 kB/s)
...........
...........
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
+ sudo -E sh -c docker version
**Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64**

If you would like to use Docker as a non-root user, you should now consider
adding your user to the "docker" group with something like:

  sudo usermod -aG docker skywalker

Remember that you will have to log out and back in for this to take effect!

skywalker@skywalker-PC:~$ docker -v
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
skywalker@skywalker-PC:~$
```

Comment: But how do I update docker on Amazon Linux AMI? I tried to update yum cache and install docker, also tried the official installation script at https://get.docker.com/ but both installs version 1.11

Comment: @TuomasToivonen please check the update. Use `-fsSL` instead of `-sSL`. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Problem solved by disposing those Amazon Linux instances and use RHEL instead

Comment: @TuomasToivonen oh  that's great. Thanks for sharing.